# Image convolution with a 4D Kernel in opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, filter, convolution

Given an image, I'm trying to apply convolution with a (3 x 3 x 3 x 64) kernel:

`cv2.filter2D(img, -1, np.random.rand(3,3,3,64))`

Gives:

> error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/filterengine.hpp:363: error: (-215) anchor.inside(Rect(0, 0, ksize.width, ksize.height)) in function normalizeAnchor

In fact in the documentation it says:

> **kernel** – convolution kernel (or rather a correlation kernel), a **single-channel** floating point matrix; if you want to apply different kernels to different channels, split the image into separate color planes using split() and process them individually.

Is there any other opencv function that can convolve a > 2D kernel? Or do I have to do two for loops applying filter2d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such functionality in OpenCV - not in any of the interfaces nor the core C++ library itself.  If you want to do 4D convolution, you'll either have to use `cv2.filter2D` looping over 2D submatrices of your 4D kernel, write it yourself manually, or use something else that supports it, like a deep learning package, or SciPy.

The easiest solution I can suggest without you having to write one or hack at one yourself is to use SciPy's `scipy.signal.convolve` which performs N-dimensional convolution: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html.  Bear in mind that both image and kernel need to have the same number of dimensions, so it's expected that your image is 4D as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info! using `scipy.signal.convolve` and `np.expand_dims` might be the way to go, appreciate it.

Comment: @Kiran No worries. Glad I could help.  If you gave more information on your actual image, I'd be able to write some code for you that demonstrates how to do it... but of course if you want to discover that yourself, you're definitely more than welcome to do so.  Good luck!

Comment: I got it working! I had to figure out that filter2D does 'same' convolution but with bottom/right padding. Also, they pad in 'reflect' mode instead of constant 0s which was not great for my use case but with some numpy logic all good now. Thanks for the help @rayryeng!

Comment: Ah! I see. Yeah unfortunately the type of padding you can't specify. Either way, glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV function **cv2.filter2D()**, as the name implies, assumes a 2D img and a 2D kernel.  For more than that, you have to use loops.  For example, the following runs with no errors,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read an rgb image
img = cv2.imread('fig1.png')

# filter the first channel (blue)
out0 = cv2.filter2D( img[:,:,0], -1, np.random.rand(3,3))
```

See the documentation at [cv2.filter2D()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04)

Comment: Yeah that's how I'm doing it right now, was wondering if there was another function that did 4D but guess not.

Comment: On a conventional CPU, it would not provide any real advantage.  The loop iteration occurs once per channel, so its comparatively cheap. And, it will have the same cost whether it occurs inside the function or outside the function.  But, on a large parallel processor, c.f. a GPU,  there could be some significant advantage in convenience and speed.  I suspect you would need to unroll the outer loop(s) to do that, so some effort might go into making a clean API for arbitrary number of dimensions.  Maybe that API already exists in some GPU library.

Comment: Got it. This will be running on a conventional CPU so I think I'll be fine. Thanks for the help @DrM

Comment: Good, please don't forget to accept and/or up-vote if it seems correct.